# how to read in files made of double values line by line using c++

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to do something very simple, but just can't get it right...
Working with C++, I want to read in  "myfile.tsv" which looks like this:

2.3 3.3 3.4 3.5 5.6 \n
 1.2 1.3 1.2 \n
 3.4 3.5 3.5 \n
 4.4 4.6 1.3 1.5 \n
...

many lines of double values, each line may have different size.

I want to read in it line by line and put each line into a 
`vector<double>`, and finally save all the values in a `vector<vector<double>>`.

Thanks in advance for any tips~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use getline and stringstream

```
while(getline(file,str)){
   stringstream stream(str);
   double something;
   while(stream>>something){
       //Push it into inner vector<double>
   }
   //push vector<double> into vector<vector<double> > here
}
```

You can work out the inner details yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! and..I noticed I should clear the inner vector each time after pushing to the outer one so that it doesn't accumulate line by line.

Comment: @GinnyLi you don't need to do it if you define it inside the outer while loop

Answer (score 0):

I have used `string` and `stringstream` to emulate your file.
Below is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str = "2.3 3.3 3.4 3.5 5.6 \n 1.2 1.3 1.2 \n 3.4 3.5 3.5 \n 4.4 4.6 1.3 1.5 \n";
    stringstream ss(str);
    double temp = 0.0; 
    vector<vector<double>> vec1;
    string s;
    while(getline(ss,s,'\n'))
    {
        cout<<s<<endl;
        vector<double> vec;
        stringstream ireadString(s);
        while(ireadString>>temp)
        {
            vec.push_back(temp);
        }
        vec1.push_back(vec);
    }
    vector<vector<double>>::iterator itr = vec1.begin();
    for (; itr != vec1.end() ; itr++)
    {
        vector<double> v = *itr;
        for (vector<double>::iterator itr1 = v.begin(); itr1 != v.end() ; itr1++)
            cout<<*itr1<<'\t';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is shown how it can be done

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream if( "input.txt" );

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v;

    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( if, line ) )
    {   
        std::istringstream is( line );
        v.emplace_back( std::vector<double>( std::istream_iterator<double>( is ), 
                                             std::istream_iterator<double>() ) ); 
    }        

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( double x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If the filw contains the following data

```
2.3 3.3 3.4 3.5 5.6 \n 1.2 1.3 1.2 \n 3.4 3.5 3.5 \n 4.4 4.6 1.3 1.5 \n
```

then the output will be

```
2.3 3.3 3.4 3.5 5.6 
1.2 1.3 1.2 
3.4 3.5 3.5 
4.4 4.6 1.3 1.5
```